# Flexslider and Rails 4

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, flexslider

I am trying to get Flexslider to work in my page setup and it is displaying nothing in the space where the slider should be appearing. What am I missing?

Show.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "flexslider.css", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.flexslider.js", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider();
 });
</script>




<div>
    <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <%= image_tag('carousel_1.jpg') %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= image_tag('carousel_2.jpg') %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= image_tag('carousel_3.jpg') %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.flexslider
//= require d3.js
//= require_tree .
```

application.css

```
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require bootstrap_extensions
 *= require flexslider.css
 *= require_self
 *= require style
 */
```

**Update**

After working on this some more, I am now receiving an error:

> TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function $('.flexslider').flexslider({

and

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: There are too many possibilities as to what could be the problem here. Please provide more information to help pinpoint the issue (links real? images exist? console errors? etc.)

Comment: It is not giving any console errors, not errors show in Firebug. Without the css file in the pipeline the images all show in a list format. The server scroll is giving no errors. I cannot think of other files that would be pertinent to this issue.  The jquery and css files are taken directly from the github page.

Comment: Ok, so in all of fussing with it, I am now getting a couple of errors in the firebug console.

    TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function
 $('.flexslider').flexslider({

and    SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
 

<!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question. When I downloaded the .js files from github, my computer downloaded the entire html file of the page holding the script. This was causing the Syntax Error as it was not expecting the DOCTYPE HTML information in the js file. Once I set up the proper information in the file everything ran smoothly. It is a lesson in checking all of my files to make sure they are imported properly.